# Reversing a linked list - Error says found cycle

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, reverse

I wrote the following code to reverse a linked list, but not sure what I am doing incorrectly. This is from a sample [problem here](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/) that asks to reverse a linked list.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */

/**
 * @param {ListNode} head
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var reverseList = function(head) {
    function traverse(node) {
        if(!node.next) return node;
        else {
            let currentNode = node.next;
            let nextNode = traverse(node.next);
            nextNode.next = currentNode;
            return nextNode;
        }
    }
    
    return traverse(head);
};
```

For the given input , `[4,5]`, when I try to run it says `Error - Found cycle in the ListNode`. Could someone please explain what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You did not clear `head.next`, it still points to the second (now next-to-last) node

Comment: Btw, are you sure that `reverseList` should mutate the nodes in the list? Creating and returning a new list would be much easier and less error-prone

Comment: @Bergi Could you give an example with an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're always returning last node of linked list in `traverse(node.next)` which then changes it's next causing a loop to get formed.
Consider a linked list, 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4.
Recursive calls are:
`traverse(1) -> traverse(2) -> traverse(3) -> traverse(4)`

> traverse(4) - returns 4.
> traverse(3) - 4.next=3 and returns 4.
> traverse(2) - 4.next=2 and returns 4.
> traverse(1) - 4.next=1 and returns 4.

Hence, a cyclic linked list is formed: 1->2->3->4->1...

Instead you should change the next in place during traverse call, similar to this:

```
var reverseList = function(head) {
    function traverse(node) {
        if(!node || !node.next) return node;
        else {
            let currentNode = node;
            let nextNode = node.next;
            let head = traverse(node.next);
            nextNode.next = currentNode;
            currentNode.next = null;
            return head;
        }
    }
    
    return traverse(head);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why we need recursion here. We just need to keep track of the next node to alter and the head of the new list. Like:

```js
var reverseList = function(head) {
  let newHead = null;

  while (head) {
    const node = head;
    head = node.next;
    node.next = newHead;
    newHead = node;
  }

  return newHead;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you did not clear `head.next`, it still points to the second (now next-to-last) node. You could fix this by doing

```
const last = traverse(head);
last.next = null;
return last;
```

but this code is still buggy as it can only handle non-empty lists, and really it probably should not mutate the argument list at all but rather produce a new one. That immutable style is also much, much simpler:

```
/**
 * @param {ListNode} head
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
function reverseList(head) {
    function traverse(node, tail) {
        if (!node) return tail;
        else return traverse(node.next, new ListNode(node.val, tail));
    }
    return traverse(head, null);
}
```